# How can I make a box (div) go below the boxes that i put before

Tags: html, css

Im starting with CSS and I was working to make something like this:

[image: example]

but for some reason when I'm adding the 5th box, using a div, this goes below the other to boxes and it looks like this:

[image: my work]

can you please tell me how to fix it? Im putting the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cajas en CSS </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos3.css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="red">
        <div class="ejemplo0"> .</div>
        <div class="ejemplo1"> .</div>
        <div class="cont1">
            <div class="ejemplo2">.</div>
            <div class="ejemplo3">.</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class ="ejemplo4">.</div>
        
        <div class="cont2">
            <div class="ejemplo5">.</div>
            <div class="ejemplo6">.</div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: CSS code 1]

[image: CSS code 2]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Please check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Comment: can you please post the css code here in text.Its annoying to OCR it. Some suggestions ,  arrange the ```divs``` in the order you want the result.post the css for further solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your problem is that you are not clearing the float for the .ejemplo4

please check this code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cajas en CSS </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos3.css">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="red">
        <div class="ejemplo0"> .</div>
        <div class="ejemplo1"> .</div>
        <div class="cont1">
            <div class="ejemplo2">.</div>
            <div class="ejemplo3">.</div>
        </div>
        <div class='clear'>
        
        </div>
        <div class ="ejemplo4">.</div>
        
        <div class="cont2">
            <div class="ejemplo5">.</div>
            <div class="ejemplo6">.</div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS
.ejemplo0{
width:100%;
height:200px;
background:#222;
}
.ejemplo1{

```
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:#aaa;
}
.cont1,.cont2{
  width:100%;
  height:250px;
  background:#eee;
}
.ejemplo4{
    width:100%;
  height:200px;
  background:#000;
}
.ejemplo2,.ejemplo3,.ejemplo5,.ejemplo6{
  width:48%;
  margin:1%;
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}
.ejemplo2,.ejemplo3{
  background:red;
}
.ejemplo5,.ejemplo6{
background:yellow;  
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

you can also check the result here: https://jsfiddle.net/srx0kpn1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the height of cont1 like this:

```
.cont1{
width: 95%;
height: 400px;
margin: 2px auto;}
```

and if you want to set more divs below the second container (cont2) you should do the same thing.